# Getting programs install date using c++

Tags: windows

I want to get the install date of some specific programs using c++ . I know that I can search the registry at *SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall* path but some keys dont have the InstallDate value, despite the fact that in Programs and Features, where the programs installed are listed, the date appears.

Comment: Did you check under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`?

Comment: This is not a C++ question, rather a Windows question.

Comment: NathanOliver, can't find what I need at that path. YSC, sorry

Comment: Use WMI to to enumerate Win32_Product